# How does client-side caching of JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

I was wondering how browsers determine when to fetch a script from the server vs from the cache...

When developing, I never have to clear my cache to see changes. However, some people often experience problems with their browser caching scripts and not fetching a newer version. I know you can append a query string to the filepath to force it to fetch from the server, but in this question I'm more interested in understanding the mechanics behind the problem. Why does the cache interfere only sometimes and why does it not effect everyone the same?

Also, how might this differ from browser to browser? IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc...

Thanks

Comment: Caches are everywhere, server-side and client-side.  For the purpose of this question, I assume you are only asking about the client-side.  I suggest downloading Fiddler and/or Wireshark to look at the raw responses coming from the server.  Caching directives are in the form of HTTP headers, and caching behavior depends on headers in both the request and the response.

Comment: As a developer, you are likely to have in-browser dev tools open, and in some cases that means your browser is not caching, that may be why you seem to not have issues with it, while someone else does.

Comment: I think your question is too broad, there are so [many different caching techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcache%5d%20browser%20is%3aquestion) that apply to browsers… Yes, this might differ from browser to browser because of technology support, implementation bugs and configuration rules.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I'm aware of using query strings to force the file to be fetched from the server. What I'm trying to get at is, how does the browser determine if it's going to fetch from the server? Does it, do cached files have an expiration date at which the browser fetches it again or?...

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache#Cache_control).

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, this is a pretty broad question, and I believe it really depends from browser to browser. More often than not, your browser will cache things like images, css, and js files to reduce page load times when visiting the site again.

If you're worried about your audience being able to view your new content or functionality, one 'easy' method is to version your js and css files. This can be done by doing something like this:

script type="text/javascript" src="someplace/main.js?ver=1.5" >

Notice the ? after the js extension. This simply tells the browser that there is more data to process. If it does not recognize the string, it will attempt to download the file again, thus, updating your client side cache.